# Date Pipe in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have a problem with the handling of dates in angular 8.

I have an api rest with symfony4 (apiPlatform) and it returns the dates with this format

```
"balanceDate": "2010-10-04T00:00:00+00:00"
```

If I pass it to my template without the applied Date pipe it puts exactly the same text

```
2010-10-04T00:00:00+00:00
```

when I use the pipe as follows in angular

```
{‌{ balanceDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

The date is represented with one day less
[image]

I have been doing tests, I manually added the date to the pipe and I was deleting parts of the date

```
{‌{ '2010-10-04T00:00:00+00:00' | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }} - Fail
{‌{ '2010-10-04' | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }} - Correct
{‌{ '2010-10-04T00:00:00' | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }} - Correct
```

So I deduced that this part of the date

```
+00:00
```

It is the cause of the problem

I honestly have no idea on which side I should work the date output, whether in Angular or in the symfony api rest.

I hope you can guide me to solve this problem

Thank you

Comment: It is converting the datetime to local time because of the time zone. I mean, it is subtracting some hours. Datetime is hell in javascript...

Comment: yes thats true. I could suggest use a lib for that, moment (but its heavy) and date-fns, lighter than moment but not as much functions I think.

Comment: If you wanted to handle it the front end you could extend the built in pipe and use some localization/normalization with momentjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the date is set as a UTC value ("+00:00" or "Z" for the timezone), you can add the timezone specifier to the date pipe:

```
date:'dd-MM-yyyy':'UTC'
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to passe the string date to the Object Date of javascript to get a valid Object Date Javascript in the component before to use it on the template:

```
newdate = new Date('2010-10-04T00:00:00+00:00');
```

demo: [Demo Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkpz9m)